# bidi package fail with recent version of multicol

Tags: multicol, right-to-left, bidi, patching

I have this simple example of `multicol` in RTL document with `bidi` package. Version of `multicol` package in my TL2021 is 1.9b  result after compilation with xelatex is incorrect

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[rldocument]{bidi}

\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Solved in the [bidi](https://ctan.org/pkg/bidi) package update version 36.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment this is due to fixes that have been done to internal commands of multicol and which are not reflected (so far) in the patches done by bidi.

As a temporary fix if it turns out that Ulrike's suggested patches aren't sufficient, you can roll back multicol individually as follows (unfortunately you have to go a long way back as I didn't add a rollback for 1.8).

Try this:

```
\usepackage{multicol}[=2018-01-01]
```

in your documents until the time bidi gets updated.

Answer (score 6):

You could try this (but there is lots of guessing involved, so I don't know if it will also work in more complicated cases):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[rldocument]{bidi}

\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\LTR@column@boxes{\mult@gfirstbox}{\mult@firstbox}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\RTL@column@boxes{\mult@gfirstbox}{\mult@firstbox}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\RTL@column@boxes{\mult@gfirstbox}{\mult@firstbox}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, patching of multicol with bidi needs to be changed ?

Comment: @SalimBou yes. multicol got corrected in  some places and bidi overwrites internals of multicol and this now doesn't any longer fit together. This is why we put out latex-dev releases so that people can test out upcoming changes a month or two prior them showing up in the main release. Unfortunately no bidi user seems to have used xelatex-dev together with bidi this time.

Comment: The relevant change is probably https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/701  and maybe https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/682