# Disappear part of some text in multicols with xepersian package

Tags: multicol, xepersian

Happy new year.

The first columns in the `multicols` environment disappear when using `xepersian` package. (I updated TeX Live today)

versions:

```
multicol.sty    2021/10/28 v1.9b multicolumn formatting (FMi)
xepersian.sty    2020/05/17 v23.1 Persian typesetting in XeLaTeX
fontspec.sty    2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Amiri} % This font have been installed with TeX Live

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\listfiles
\begin{document}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
    متن آزمایشی متن آزمایشی متن آزمایشی متن آزمایشی متن آزمایشی
    متن آزمایشی متن آزمایشی متن آزمایشی متن آزمایشی متن آزمایشی
    متن آزمایشی متن آزمایشی متن آزمایشی متن آزمایشی متن آزمایشی
    
    متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر
    متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر
    متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر متن دیگر 
    \end{multicols}
    
\end{document}
```

---

Output:

[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/624280/2388, there is also already an issue in the bidi github https://github.com/persiantex/bidi/issues/22, but the maintainer seems not to be active currently.