# Multicol column disappears when using beamer + polyglossia arabic

Tags: beamer, multicol, polyglossia, arabic, texlive-2021

Here is a (meaningless) beamer slide

[image]

which I get with the following minimal code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=usmax]{english}%
%\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Uttering Words}

\begin{multicols}{2}
Blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla
 blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
 blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla \end{multicols}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and here is what happens when I load Arabic language for polyglossia by uncommenting line 5 in the code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=usmax]{english}%
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Uttering Words}

\begin{multicols}{2}
Blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla
 blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
 blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla \end{multicols}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It made the left column disappear, even though there is not a single Arabic word in the document.

The problem with this example is that I get the problem on my machine (running XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 and TeX Live 2021) but I don't get the problem on overleaf (running the same versions of XeTeX and TeXlive).

I compared the log files on overleaf and on my machine, the differences are just a few package versions that are slightly different (on overleaf, multicol.sty was from 2019, on my machine it is from 2021, on overleaf LaTeX2e is version LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1, on my machine it is LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1, and some other such minimal differences). My file versions are systematically more recent than the ones on overleaf.

Where does the problem come from? What causes this problem on my machine's TeXlive 2021 and not on overleaf's TeXlive 2021? Do you have the same problem on your machine?

Comment: try this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/624278/2388

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Ulrike, patron saint of TeXers in distress, who deserves a statue, a monument, a shrine… I was able to solve the problem using Frank's patch:

```
\makeatletter
\def\process@cols#1#2{\count@#1\relax
     \loop
% add debug code
     \typeout{Looking at box \the\count@}
      #2%
     \advance\count@\tw@
     \ifnum\count@<\doublecol@number
   \repeat}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble of the document. I hope this solution will be included in TeXlive 2022 so that other wretches like me stay away from dangers, toils and snares!